# How to fix the Telethon's exception BadMessageError

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, telethon

I'm doing an application to download all files form a Telegram channel. When downloading I receive the error message:

```
telethon.errors.rpcbaseerrors.BadMessageError: Message too old, and it cannot be verified 
whether the server has received a message with this msg_id or not.
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which channel do you test?
Can I give me the username of your channel for test?

Comment: It's "matematicaEmPDF". It's a channel about math.

Answer (score 1):

I test and download all files by this code and it was fine. (such as `Fundamentos_de_Matemática_Elementar.pdf`)

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = XXXXX
api_hash = 'a191b0c8c7d88a1c34XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+98937XXXXXXXX'
######################t##########################
channel_username = 'matematicaEmPDF'
################################################

client = TelegramClient(phone_number,
                    api_id,
                    api_hash,        
        )

client.start(phone=phone_number)

# ---------------------------------------
msgs = client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=100)

for msg in msgs.data:
    if msg.media is not None:
        client.download_media(message=msg)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. Try download 800 files. You will see the exception.

Comment: I think the telegram does not allow downloading too old files. That's why you'll be faced with this exception.

Comment: I think that is a question of session time. I'm downloading step by step. When the connection is refused I start to download again and I ignore the total downloaded files. So, all the time I'm advancing in this queue.